# Public transport travel time of a group of addresses

Tags: google-maps

I have a list of 200 addressed plus my home address: let's call the first ones A, B, C... and my home address simply "Home".

Is there any fast method to calculate on Google Maps, **in bulk**, all the 200 estimated times to travel "Home - A; Home - B; Home - C ...etc" using only public transport means?

If not, do you know any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Google Maps Distance Matrix API, but you'll have to do some (fairly basic) programming. A description of how to do it is well beyond the scope of an answer here -- check out the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the TravelTime API ([documentation here](http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/overview/introduction))- you just need to do a few API calls to get this data back and uses public transport timetables (as well as driving / walking / cycling)

If you're  just looking for the raw data export without writing code this is possible from http://www.traveltimeplatform.com/analytics/

(Disclaimer: I work for TravelTime platform who are the creators of the api and analytics platform)